# How to quickly save/load class instance to file

Tags: c#, .net, file, serialization

I have several collections of classes/structs in my app.

The class is just a class with fields

```
class A
{
  public int somevalue;
  public string someothervalue
}
```

And my collection

```
List<A> _myList;
```

I need to be able to save _myList and load. I just want to save all class fields to file and load. I don't want to spend time writing my own save/load. Are there any tools in .NET to help me. I don't care about the file format.

Comment: How large is this collection?  How many of these class(es) are you going to want to place in the collection?  Your response to this comment will depend on which answer I post.

Comment: quite a few, less than a hundred. This is just a test project where app is loading collection at startup and saves when exits. I just don't want to spend time on that. Because I am constatly adding new classes and collections.

Comment: Do you want to save fields or properties? Some serializers(BinarySerializer) work on the fields, others (XmlSerializer) work on public properties.

Comment: Good question. I am fine with public fields only.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

XMLSerializer isn't hard to use.  As long as your objects aren't huge, it's pretty quick.  I serialize out some huge objects in a few of my apps.  It takes forever and the resulting files are almost 100 megs, but they're editable should I need to tweak some stuff.  Plus it doesn't matter if I add fields to my objects.  The serialized files of the older version of the object still deserialize properly..  I do the serialization on a separate thread so it doesn't matter how long it takes in my case.  The caveat is that your `A` class has to have a constructor for XMLSerialziation to work.

Here's some working code I use to serialize/deserialize with the error handling ripped out for readibility...

```
private List<A> Load()
{
    string file = "filepath";
    List<A> listofa = new List<A>();
    XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(A.GetType());
    FileStream aFile = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[aFile.Length];
    aFile.Read(buffer, 0, (int)aFile.Length);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
    return (List<A>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
}


private void Save(List<A> listofa)
{
    string path = "filepath";
    FileStream outFile = File.Create(path);
    XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(A.GetType());
    formatter.Serialize(outFile, listofa);
}
```

Comment: What's `coilsfile` in your demo?

Comment: Looks like that was a typo.  Tried to remove anything specific to the code, and the original `FileStream` was probably called `coilsfile`. In my clean up effort, I neglected to rename `coilsfile` to `aFile`.  But it's been three years now, so hard to tell.  Good catch, though. Wow.  Edited to reflect this.

Comment: Please, please, please use "using" when opening a FileStream and a MemoryStream to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 31):

I just wrote [a blog post on saving an object's data to Binary, XML, or Json](http://blog.danskingdom.com/saving-and-loading-a-c-objects-data-to-an-xml-json-or-binary-file/); well writing an object or list of objects to a file that is. Here are the functions to do it in the various formats. See my blog post for more details.

### Binary

```
/// <summary>
/// Writes the given object instance to a binary file.
/// <para>Object type (and all child types) must be decorated with the [Serializable] attribute.</para>
/// <para>To prevent a variable from being serialized, decorate it with the [NonSerialized] attribute; cannot be applied to properties.</para>
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of object being written to the XML file.</typeparam>
/// <param name="filePath">The file path to write the object instance to.</param>
/// <param name="objectToWrite">The object instance to write to the XML file.</param>
/// <param name="append">If false the file will be overwritten if it already exists. If true the contents will be appended to the file.</param>
public static void WriteToBinaryFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false)
{
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, append ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create))
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, objectToWrite);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Reads an object instance from a binary file.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of object to read from the XML.</typeparam>
/// <param name="filePath">The file path to read the object instance from.</param>
/// <returns>Returns a new instance of the object read from the binary file.</returns>
public static T ReadFromBinaryFile<T>(string filePath)
{
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        return (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

### XML

Requires the System.Xml assembly to be included in your project.

```
/// <summary>
/// Writes the given object instance to an XML file.
/// <para>Only Public properties and variables will be written to the file. These can be any type though, even other classes.</para>
/// <para>If there are public properties/variables that you do not want written to the file, decorate them with the [XmlIgnore] attribute.</para>
/// <para>Object type must have a parameterless constructor.</para>
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of object being written to the file.</typeparam>
/// <param name="filePath">The file path to write the object instance to.</param>
/// <param name="objectToWrite">The object instance to write to the file.</param>
/// <param name="append">If false the file will be overwritten if it already exists. If true the contents will be appended to the file.</param>
public static void WriteToXmlFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false) where T : new()
{
    TextWriter writer = null;
    try
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, append);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, objectToWrite);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (writer != null)
            writer.Close();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Reads an object instance from an XML file.
/// <para>Object type must have a parameterless constructor.</para>
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of object to read from the file.</typeparam>
/// <param name="filePath">The file path to read the object instance from.</param>
/// <returns>Returns a new instance of the object read from the XML file.</returns>
public static T ReadFromXmlFile<T>(string filePath) where T : new()
{
    TextReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.Close();
    }
}
```

### Json

You must include a reference to Newtonsoft.Json assembly, which can be obtained from the [Json.NET NuGet Package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json).

```
/// <summary>
/// Writes the given object instance to a Json file.
/// <para>Object type must have a parameterless constructor.</para>
/// <para>Only Public properties and variables will be written to the file. These can be any type though, even other classes.</para>
/// <para>If there are public properties/variables that you do not want written to the file, decorate them with the [JsonIgnore] attribute.</para>
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of object being written to the file.</typeparam>
/// <param name="filePath">The file path to write the object instance to.</param>
/// <param name="objectToWrite">The object instance to write to the file.</param>
/// <param name="append">If false the file will be overwritten if it already exists. If true the contents will be appended to the file.</param>
public static void WriteToJsonFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false) where T : new()
{
    TextWriter writer = null;
    try
    {
        var contentsToWriteToFile = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToWrite);
        writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, append);
        writer.Write(contentsToWriteToFile);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (writer != null)
            writer.Close();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Reads an object instance from an Json file.
/// <para>Object type must have a parameterless constructor.</para>
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of object to read from the file.</typeparam>
/// <param name="filePath">The file path to read the object instance from.</param>
/// <returns>Returns a new instance of the object read from the Json file.</returns>
public static T ReadFromJsonFile<T>(string filePath) where T : new()
{
    TextReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
        var fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(fileContents);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.Close();
    }
}
```

### Example

```
// Write the list of objects to a file.
WriteToXmlFile<List<A>>("C:\myObjects.txt", _myList);

// Read the list of objects from the file back into a variable.
List<A> _myList = ReadFromXmlFile<List<A>>("C:\myObjects.txt");
```

Comment: FYI that the BinaryFormatter is being phased out starting with .NET 5. Read more [here](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/better-obsoletion/binaryformatter-obsoletion.md). Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64799591/is-there-a-high-performance-way-to-replace-the-binaryformatter-in-net5) for some alternative approaches to the BinaryFormatter.

Answer (score 5):

Old topic, but I modified Tim Coker's answer above to utilize the using blocks to properly dispose of the stream objects and save only a single class instance at a time:

```
public static T Load<T>(string FileSpec) {
    XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (FileStream aFile = new FileStream(FileSpec, FileMode.Open)) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[aFile.Length];
        aFile.Read(buffer, 0, (int)aFile.Length);

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer)) {
            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}

public static void Save<T>(T ToSerialize, string FileSpec) {
    Directory.CreateDirectory(FileSpec.Substring(0, FileSpec.LastIndexOf('\\')));
    FileStream outFile = File.Create(FileSpec);
    XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    formatter.Serialize(outFile, ToSerialize);
}
```

Comment: You need to dispose outFile after you use it, or use using. You properly disposed the Streams in Load but not in Save.

Answer (score 4):

There are many serializers:

**Part of .net framework**

- XmlSerializer (standardized format, slow and verbose)
- BinarySerializer (proprietary format, medium speed, *supports cyclic graphs*, serializes fields instead of properties => *annoying versioning*)

**3rd party:**

- Json-Serializers (standardized format, text-based, shorter than xml)
- ProtoBuf-Serializers (standardized format, binary, very fast)

I'd probably use a ProtoBuf Serializer if the file may be binary, and a json serializer if it needs to be plain-text.

Comment: The DataContractJsonSerializer is part of 3.5 and above (System.Runtime.Serialization.Json). Although for this specific instance, the BinaryFormatter would be a good choice.

Comment: I don't the standard BinaryFormatter because its file format is opaque and its use of private fields breaks encapsulation and causes versioning problem.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the XML Serilizer, is fast, easy to implement and keep the objects in a hummand readable fashion, you can see a nice [example](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/csharp/xmlserializer-example.htm).

You can use a binary serialization if you want a more size effective obfustated solution. (for example if you want to transmit the serialization over a network.)

**EDIT:** To get more control over the elements you serialize take a look of this [example](http://weblogs.asp.net/wim/archive/2004/08/12/213700.aspx)

Comment: Great example. But. The container is wrapped in Serializable class. How can serialize 'just the one variable of type List<>'.

Comment: Hi, you need to use XmlArray and XmlArrayItem control attributes, take a look to the new example. You must serialize the container of the list and the list have to be a public property.

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize your `List<>` using XML serializer or Binary Serializer and save the serialized list into a file.

Later , you can read this file content and retrieve your original list.

Make your type for which you are creating list `[Serializable]`

Comment: Thanks. What about Dictionary<>? The same? Or my own IEnumerable/IEnumerator collection

Answer (score 0):

We can save and load objects from file in one of the following ways.

> BinarySerialization,XmlSerialization,JsonSerialization

```
public enum Serialization
{
    BinarySerialization = 1,
    XmlSerialization = 2,
    JsonSerialization = 3,
}
public static void SaveObjectToFile<T>(Serialization serialization, string filePath ,T objectToSave)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath.Substring(0, filePath.LastIndexOf('\\')));
     using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
    {
        switch (serialization)
        {
            case Serialization.XmlSerialization: //Object type must have a parameterless constructor
                XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                //Use the [XmlIgnore] attribute to exclude a public property or variable from being written to the file.(in XML Serialization only)
                formatter.Serialize(writer, objectToSave);
                break;
            case Serialization.JsonSerialization: //Object type must have a parameterless constructor
                var contentsToWriteToFile = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSave);
                //[JsonIgnore] attribute to exclude a public property or variable from being written to the file.
                writer.Write(contentsToWriteToFile);
                break;
            case Serialization.BinarySerialization: 
                var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
                //decorate class (and all classes that it contains) with a [Serializable] attribute.Use the [NonSerialized] attribute to exclude a variable from being written to the file;
                binaryFormatter.Serialize(writer.BaseStream, objectToSave);
                break;
        }
    }
}
public static T LoadObjectToFile<T>(Serialization serialization, string filePath)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        switch (serialization)
        {
            case Serialization.XmlSerialization:
                XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                return (T)formatter.Deserialize(reader);
            case Serialization.JsonSerialization:
                var fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(fileContents);
            case Serialization.BinarySerialization:
                var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
                return (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(reader.BaseStream);
            default:
                 throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Serialization = "+Convert.ToString(serialization));
        }
    }
}
```