# C# Store variables after program closes

Tags: c#, variables, store

Is there any simple way to store variable when my game closes and load it when it opens next time? Even better would be if I could store instance of my class and then load it.

Comment: write it to a text file and read it on startup?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266875/how-to-quickly-save-load-class-instance-to-file or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115721/how-to-save-restore-serializable-object-to-from-file.

Comment: What do you want to store?  Is this like a saved game, or are these settings for how your application should run?

Comment: You could serilize your class and read it next time the game gets started

Comment: You could try the Settings class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx Scroll down to the bit about using settings at run time

Comment: There are too many ways to do this, though given your wish, serialisation and dumpt to a file looks like the best one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) to serialize the instance of a class. And upon loading all you have to do is deserialize it, everything is done by the library.

Serialization example:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "Expiry": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small"
//  ]
//}
```

Deserialization example:

```
string json = @"{
  'Name': 'Bad Boys',
  'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00',
  'Genres': [
    'Action',
    'Comedy'
  ]
}";

Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);

string name = m.Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize the `object` to an `.xml` file or to a `DB` and on load `deserialize` it and you will have the object in the `memory`.