# How to write a list of classes to a file in UWP C#

Tags: c#, uwp, file-writing, file-access

I have attempted to use the methods on this thread by deadlydog:
[How to quickly save/load class instance to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266875/how-to-quickly-save-load-class-instance-to-file)

This works in a console application for writing a list of classes to a file. However when I try migrating it to a UWP project I always get **"Access to the path ..... is denied"**

According to this thread: [broadFileSystemAccess UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559764/broadfilesystemaccess-uwp)
I am meant to add broadFileSystemAccess capabilities, which I have done.

However, it also says that I need to use **StorageFile APIs**, not just classic **System.IO API**.

I believe the current writing method I am using is **utilizing the System.IO API** but I do not know how to achieve the same goal using **StorageFile APIs**.

Could someone please point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Is this a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59598401/how-to-use-system-io-serializers-in-uwp-with-windows-storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP apps are only allowed to write to a small subset of folders on your machine. Using broadFileSystemAccess capability might alleviate it, but it's like using a sledgehammer when you need a screwdriver.

Your application to write data it needs to [Windows.Store.ApplicationData.LocalFolder.Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalFolder). That folder is writable without any special capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the System.IO API, just be sure your code doesn't try to access anything outside its StorageFolder. You can get the StorageFolder path at runtime with this code

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path
```

There is also documentation for how to handle IO in UWP here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files