# How to use System.IO Serializers in UWP with Windows.Storage

Tags: c#, uwp, storage, xmlserializer, storagefile

I want to be able to have a list of class objects (`List<Class>`) and be able to easily write and read to a text file.

In my older **Console Applications** and **Windows Forms** applications I used to use:

```
List<Class> _myList = ... 
WriteToFile<List<Class>>("C:\\...\\Test.txt", Class _myList)

public static void WriteToFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false) where T : new()
        {
            TextWriter writer = null;
            try
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, append);
                serializer.Serialize(writer, objectToWrite);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (writer != null)
                    writer.Close();
            }
        }
```

However this does not work in a **UWP application** and I have to use `StorageFolder` and `StorageFile` which works fine for writing simple text to a file like this:

```
StorageFolder folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile file= await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("Test.txt");
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, "Example Write Text");
```

But I want to be able to use the more advanced functionality of `XmlSerializer` along with `StreamWriter` to write lists of classes to a file within my UWP application.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Stream`-based versions the methods you use, for example `StreamWriter` has a constructor which takes a `System.IO.Stream` instance.

To get a `System.IO.Stream` from a `StorageFile`, you can use the [`OpenStreamForWriteAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.windowsruntimestorageextensions.openstreamforwriteasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) and [`OpenStreamForReadAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.windowsruntimestorageextensions.openstreamforreadasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) extension methods, which are in the `System.IO` namespace on UWP:

```
//add to the top of the file
using System.IO;

//in your code
var stream = await myStorageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
//do something, e.g.
var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);
```